# Django REST Framework - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django REST Framework` to write `REST API`.

my **settings.py** contains settings for DRF

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ]
}
```

and every request must be signed using any of the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` method.

In **contacts/serializers.py**

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    phone_numbers = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(source='contactphonenumber_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_numbers')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_numbers = validated_data.pop('contactphonenumber_set')
        emails = validated_data.pop('contactemail_set')
        instance = Contact.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for phone_data in phone_numbers:
            ContactPhoneNumber.objects.create(contact=instance, **phone_data)
        return instance
```

`print(validated_data)` gives following data

```
{'first_name': 'Anshuman', 'last_name': 'Upadhyay', 'date_of_birth': datetime.date(2018, 5, 15), 'contactphonenumber_set': [], 'user_id': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: anuj>>}
```

The `user_id` is `SimpleLazyObject` thus giving error on save

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'
```

The error is on the line `instance = Contact.objects.create(**validated_data)`

**How can I pass authenticated user to `user` field?**

> Edit 2: **contacts/models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**contacts/views.py**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `self.context` for this http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

If you are using `GenericAPIView` context is passed automatically

First of all you don't need to pass `user_id` to your serializer and then you need to update your `ContactSerializer` to look like this.

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    phone_numbers = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(source='contactphonenumber_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_numbers')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_numbers = validated_data.pop('contactphonenumber_set')
        emails = validated_data.pop('contactemail_set')
        instance = Contact.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
        for phone_data in phone_numbers:
            ContactPhoneNumber.objects.create(contact=instance, **phone_data)
        return instance
```

You shouldn't overwrite `perform_create`

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Contact.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: `exclude` is not working as I have added `fields` to the `Meta` class. (updated question with fields after getting error)

Comment: Those fields are there from earlier even though there was `user_id` field.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I was just saying that you asked to exclude `user` field as there was `user_id` in the validated_field, but it is still there even if `user` is not in the `fields` tuple.

Comment: still getting same error as given in question. Although `print(self.context['request'].user)` prints current user, the error seems to be with `user_id` field which contains `SimpleLazyObject` object

Comment: why is there an extra `user_id` field in the data?

Comment: added **views.py**. Also I would like to let you know earlier the model field was `user_id` instead of `user` which I later changed to `user` and `makemigration` and `migrate`. could this be the cause of appending `user_id`?

Comment: @AnujTBE see update, you shouldn't overwrite `perform_create`, this is where your `user_id` coming from just delete it from view

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Contact` model contains an FK relation with `AuthUserModel`. So, your instance creation statement must be like this,

```
user = get some user instance from `validated` data
instance = Contact.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
```

This is the general solution for your question, If you add your `Contact` model, we could help you more

**UPDATE-1**
Change your `create()` as below,

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    phone_numbers = validated_data.pop('contactphonenumber_set')
    emails = validated_data.pop('contactemail_set')
    user = validated_data.pop('user') # change 1
    instance = Contact.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data) # # change 2
    for phone_data in phone_numbers:
        ContactPhoneNumber.objects.create(contact=instance, **phone_data)
    return instance
```

**Update-2**
You could use `user = serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` in serializer as below,

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    phone_numbers = ContactPhoneNumberSerializer(source='contactphonenumber_set', many=True)
    user = serializers.CurrentUserDefault()

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'full_name', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_numbers')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        phone_numbers = validated_data.pop('contactphonenumber_set')
        emails = validated_data.pop('contactemail_set')
        user = validated_data.pop('user_id') 
        instance = Contact.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data) 
        for phone_data in phone_numbers:
            ContactPhoneNumber.objects.create(contact=instance, **phone_data)
        return instance
```

`CurrentUserDefault()` is do the same job as `self.context.get('request').user`

Comment: added **contacts/models.py**

Comment: please gave a look at **UPDATE-1** section

Comment: so will `'user'` field contain the authenticated user, no matter whether it is token based authentication or session based authentication?

Comment: Currently, NO, Is that you want?

Comment: yes, since it is authentication based application, I do not want to manually add user field to form but it should be their in `request` like how it work in web view using `self.request.user`

Comment: updated the answer as per your request, please try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171177/discussion-between-anuj-tbe-and-jerin-peter-george).

Comment: what is the need of `CurrentUserDefault()` if we are not using it in **create()**?

Comment: Suppose if you have a field `user` and it's `NULL` in DB. In common case, the serializer will show `null`, But, if you use `CurrentUserDefault()`, it will convert the `null` to current logged-in user